# How to filter data frame with checboxInput in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want to filter columns with checboxInput.

```
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(Column1 = c(1,2,3),
                 Column2 = c(1,2,3))
 
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("checkbox1", "checkbox1"),
  checkboxInput("checkbox2", "checkbox2"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table <- renderTable(df[,c(input$checkbox1,input$checkbox2)])
  
  # or like this
  # v_checkboxes <- reactive(input$checkbox1,input$checkbox2)
  # output$table <- renderTable(df[,c(v_checkboxes)])
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I got this errors:
With inputs passed **directly** to **df[,]**
*Warning: Error in <-: invalid subscript type 'list'*

With **v_checkboxes**
*Warning: Error in $: Can't access reactive value 'checkbox2' outside of reactive consumer.
i Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?*

I really don't know what I am missing.

**PS.** It can be checkboxGroupInput also

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when nothing is checked, the result would be a
0-column data frame – and that doesn’t play well with `renderTable()`. To
fix that, add a `req()` around the vector you’re using as a subscript. That
will prevent rendering if all values are `FALSE`. Also, as
@Ben mentioned in their comment, use `drop = FALSE` to prevent the result
from being a vector when only a single column is selected.

Here’s the revised app:

```r
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(
  Column1 = c(1, 2, 3),
  Column2 = c(1, 2, 3)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("checkbox1", "checkbox1"),
  checkboxInput("checkbox2", "checkbox2"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    df[, req(c(input$checkbox1, input$checkbox2)), drop = FALSE]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```